# getting error while reading the .xlsm file using apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to read a tempdoc.xlsm file when the following line is executed i get a IO error

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("file");

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName)); //error wen executing this line
```

when i try with the above method i just getting the following message on catch of a IO exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileName (The system cannot find the file specified)

can anyone help me with it...

but now i'm getting the followinr exception this isthe stacktrace which is as folllows

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet UploadData threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext$NamespaceContextStack.(NamespaceContext.java:78)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext$NamespaceContextStack.(NamespaceContext.java:75)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext.getNamespaceContextStack(NamespaceContext.java:98)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext.push(NamespaceContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1273)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaStringEnumerationHolderEx.enumValue(JavaStringEnumerationHolderEx.java:60)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.getEnumValue(XmlObjectBase.java:1514)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellFormulaImpl.getT(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onReadCell(XSSFSheet.java:2624)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.(XSSFRow.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initRows(XSSFSheet.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:142)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:129)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:269)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:190)
    at com.UploadData.doPost(UploadData.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: At first glance, you're trying to open "fileName" and you stated that "tempdoc.xlsm" is what you are looking for.  In any case, provide a stack trace and/or more details on the error that is occurring and the community will be better equipped to answer your question.

Comment: sorry  tempdoc.xlsm is the filename and "filename" contains the path of the file i select i do it this way String fileName = request.getParameter("file"); where file is a parameter passed by my jsp to the java servlet containing the selected file path...
wen i try with the above method  i just getting the following message on catch of a IO exception  java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileName (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the String literal "fileName" and not the variable fileName.

Try

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Note that lack of quotes around fileName.

Comment: hi i have edited the question with the stack trace after the above changes u specified

Comment: Try file you are opening is likely too big for the memory your JVM has allocated.  Read through this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap and adjust the maximum size of the heap to a more appropriate size.